# C++ Header and Main errors

Tags: c++, header, program-entry-point

This is my first time trying to integrate a header into my C++ homework. We haven't covered it in class yet, I'm just being ambitious. I'm working with Clion.

If it isn't obvious, my goal is to spell out two functions in the header, 1 to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit, the other is the opposite.

Errors:

```
/home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/main.cpp:18:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
 if (choice = 1);
 ^
/home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/main.cpp:19:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
/home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/main.cpp:23:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 else if (choice = 2)
 ^
/home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/main.cpp:27:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 else if (choice = 0)
 ^
/home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/main.cpp:31:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 else
 ^
```

functions.h header:

```
//
// Created by dylan on 7/3/16.
//

#ifndef TEMPCONVERSION_FUNCTIONS_H
#define TEMPCONVERSION_FUNCTIONS_H
#include <iostream>
int choice;
int degrees;
double degrees2;



double f2c()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the degree count in whole numbers \n";
    std::cin >> degrees;
    degrees2 = (degrees-32)/1.8;
    std::cout << degrees2;
}

double c2f()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the degree count in whole numbers \n";
    std::cin >> degrees;
    degrees2 = (degrees * 1.8) + 32;
    std::cout << degrees2;
}
#endif //TEMPCONVERSION_FUNCTIONS_H
```

main.cpp

```
include <iostream>
#include </home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/functions.h>


using namespace std;

int conMenu()
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to: \n";
    std::cout << "1. Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit \n";
    std:: cout << "2. convert Fahrenheit to Celsius \n";
    std::cout << "0. Exit the program";
    std:: cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

}

if (choice = 1);
{
double c2f();
}

else if (choice = 2)
{
double f2c();
}
else if (choice = 0)
{
return 0;
}
else
{
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't implemented a `main()` function. You should start with that.

Comment: `if` statements can be used only in functions. Perhaps you meant to put them in `main`, which you have not defined.

Comment: `=` instead of `==`.  Semi colons after `if()`. No `main()`. Variables in the `.h`. Things that look like function declarations inside if statements. Congratulations for trying to get ahead, but there is so much wrong here that you might have jumped a bit too far...

Comment: That was kind of embarrassing :).

Including main() let everything compile properly, the code is just giving me a return of 0 after executing the choice portion. So, I'll need to troubleshoot that. If I need further help, does site etiquette dictate that I make a new question, or add to this?

Comment: @Dylan add another question but look at my answer... the program works but there are mistakes everywhere. If you are trying to go further you'll encounter a huge wall because you are missing the basics

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you have an issue with integrating header files. However, the compilation errors have nothing to do with header files. You have two different issues here.

The compiler errors are because your `if()` statement is not inside any function. This is fairly obvious once you ask yourself what function is that `if()` statement a part of?

(The if statement is wrong anyway, because it's obvious that it should be using the `==` operator instead of the `=` assignment operator, but that, per se, is not the reason for the compilation errors, but this needs to be fixed too).

As far as integrating header files go: you are defining entire functions in the header files. Although, technically, there's nothing wrong with that, header files should be used only to declare functions and classes. This is true especially when you are starting to learn about header files.

Once you understand how header files work, and you know more C++, then you will be able to understand when you can, and cannot, put entire functions into header files, and what kind of functions.

Answer (score 0):

A program starts with the `main` function which you don't have and everything should be in function. Your `if` statements are outside your program which won't work

There is a difference between `=` and `==` :

`=`  is the affectation, tell something to be equal to something

`==` is used for comparaison.

Here, replace your main.cpp file with that :

```
#include <iostream>
#include </home/dylan/ClionProjects/tempconversion/functions.h>


using namespace std;

int main() // every program in C++ MUST HAVE AN int main() function
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to: \n";
    std::cout << "1. Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit \n";
    std:: cout << "2. convert Fahrenheit to Celsius \n";
    std::cout << "0. Exit the program";
    std:: cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1); // is choice equal to 1 ?
    {
        double c2f();
    }

    else if (choice == 2) // is choice equal to 2 ?
    {
        double f2c();
    }
    else if (choice == 0) // is choice equal to 0 ?
    {
        return 0;
    }

  return 0; 
// in every case, because it is "int main()" the program should return an integer, here is 0

}
```

Another problem, if a function return something, you must tell the function which data to return, for exemple `int main()` return an integer. If nothing is return, so write `void nameFunction()` because in your `functions.h` file your function actually are returning nothing but you are telling your program that they return `double` like `double f2c()`. Replace them with `void f2c()`.

**Tips**: you really should learn more about C++ programming